# Why do the sentences "I have to get a job" and "I need to get a job" mean the same thing if 'have' and 'need' are antonyms?

Tags: antonyms

For example, "I have a job" and "I need a job" are opposite statements, but "I have to get a job" and "I need to get a job" are the same. I understand that they are no longer modifying the same words, but it doesn't seem to make sense why the meaning switches.

Comment: Words have more than one meaning. Some words are their own antonyms. You just have to accept that language is not designed, it's an accumulation of millennia of people, living and dead, using it. Language does not adhere to the rules of formal logic, and we should not expect it to.

Answer (score 17):

*Have to* is a periphrastic modal idiom. *Need* is a semi-modal verb. *Must* is a modal auxiliary verb.

First, *have to* is an idiom.
*Have to* is **not** a usage of the verb *have*, in any of its senses, though it used to be.

You can tell this because *have to* is pronounced differently from *have two*, for instance.

- *I have two shovels in the driveway. (have two* = /hævtu/, with a **/v/**)
- *I have to shovel in the driveway. (have to* = /hæftu/, with an **/f/**)

This idiom is a periphrastic modal -- an idiomatic construction that means the same as a modal auxiliary verb, in this case, the verb *must*. So

- *I have to get a job = I must get a job.*
- *This has to be the place = This must be the place.*

although *have to* and *must* are quite different with negation

- *I don't have to get a job **≠** I must not get a job.*
- *This doesn't have to be the place **≠** This must not be the place.*

Second, *need* is an odd verb in a number of ways; it's called a "semi-modal" verb because it used to be a modal auxiliary verb, but, along with  *dare*, it can now only be used as a modal auxiliary verb

> Modal auxiliary verbs
>    a) must be the first auxiliary in a verb phrase,
>    b) must be followed by an infinitive without *to*,
>    c) never take tense endings, and
>    d) don't have any non-finite forms (participles, gerunds, or infinitives).

***But*** ... *need* can **only** be used this way in a negative context. I.e, it's a [Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) (NPI).

- *We don't need to consider this further = We need not consider this further.*
- *We need to consider this further* but not  **We need consider this further.*
  (the second example in each case is the modal usage; the first is not, and
  thus requires *Do*-Support, present tense marking, and an infinitive with *to*.)

So *need to* is just the ordinary usage of an ordinary verb *need*, which does not mean (though it isn't quite an opposite of) *have* in its sense of 'possess'. It does, however, mean pretty much the same thing as *have to* or *must*; all of them have similar deontic senses meaning 'be obliged to' for one reason or another.

*Have to* and  *must* also have epistemic senses, dealing with logic and probability; however, *need* seems not to have an epistemic sense. This may have been lost along with *need*'s syntactic modal superpowers as it slipped from full modal to semimodal over the centuries.

Comment: That stuff about 'need' and 'dare' is fascinating. What are your thoughts on: 'We need consider this no further' and 'I dare say this matter is closed'

Comment: Something seems amiss in this sentence: "…it used to be a modal auxiliary verb, but […] it can now only be used as a modal auxiliary verb". I'm struggling to understand what is supposed to be contrasted with what there.

Comment: Your observation on pronunciation is accent- and/or dialect-specific. Standard British English speakers don't say *have to* /hæftu/.

Comment: @AndriyM: It used to be a modal auxiliary verb **that could be used in a non-negative environment**, but it can now only be used as a modal auxiliary in a negative environment.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the word "have" differs when used in the two phrases "have to" and "have a". In the phrase "have to", the word "have" acts as a synonym for "need" in the fact that the speaker needs or has to do something. In the phrase "have a", the word "have" is used to show possession or state of being.

Welcome to the illogical world of the English language.

Comment: Actually, *have to* corresponds to *must* more than it does to *need to*. "Need to" speaks to a dependency or a requirement; "have to" speaks to an obligation. "Have to" suggests enforcement. On its own, "need to" does not. (This is perhaps a reason why some enforcement agents in the US have recently taken to using "*You need to...*": It may sound softer, but hearers know full well that it is backed up by the force of the State. It sounds almost like friendly advice about something that is good for you, something that you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Idioms are sometimes more than the some of the definitions of their parts.

*have to* and *need to* are synonyms, or closely thus with *have to* more explicitly indicating something obligatory and *need to* implying necessity without necessarily an imperative obligation.

The difference is subtle and in most cases can be used interchangeably:

> I *need to*/*have to* go to the bathroom.

Either would be valid and sufficient to explain the need, though *have to* would imply an urgency (*now*) where *need to* would normally imply *at an earliest convenience.*

Note also this would be considered more adverbial usage than usage as a verb, considering a verb is implied, if not explicitly stated, after *need to*/*have to*.

Meanwhile, the verbs *need* and *have* imply a direct object.

> I *need* a hammer.
>   (A hammer is necessary).
>   I *have* a hammer.
>   (A hammer is in my possession).

However, you can also *have to have* and *need to have* (Which mean roughly the same thing; see the first part.)

Answer (score 1):

Where did you read that they are antonyms?

The understanding of the concept antonyms can only be achieved thro one and only one language = Mathematics. Specifically, high school set theory, aided by illustration of Venn diagrams.

Like any word, the word *have* has many degrees of freedom. Each degree of freedom imbues the word with a distinct meaning.

Often, when we use a word, we use it as a combination of a few its degrees of freedom.

Similarly, the word *need* too has many degrees of freedom.

A degree of freedom = a dimension in an orthogonal dimensional framework.

The words *have* and *need* share many common dimensions, hence sharing many common meanings.

But also, there are meanings in the word *have* that fall outside the enclosure of the set of meanings of *need*, vice versa.

But a meaning of a word  being outside the set of meanings for another word  would not make them antonyms.

Otherwise, since a piano is mostly outside the range of dimensions of a television - would that make *piano* the antonym of *television* ?

To establish an antonym situation, you must narrow down to the degrees of freedom of a word, to precisely reduce your intentions to the relevant dimensions of a word,

- to establish the existence of a binary state, then we could say one state is the opposite of the other
- or to establish a spectrum/range of states with only two possible extremities, then we could say one extremity is the opposite of the other.

But, you have not established any reduction in the degrees of freedom of the two words in which their respective dimensions are in binary opposition.

Neither have you considered that the two words share common traits, aka an intersection in the Venn diagram of their degrees of freedom.