# The difference between "have got" and "have got to"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrasal-verbs, present-perfect, transatlantic-differences

I have been asked about the difference between

Have got
Have got to

Are they considered as present perfect forms?

Comment: Interesting. At least among many Brits, _I've got_ is often a paraphrase for the stative  _I have in my possession_ (etc, as in I've got a bike / a new boat / ten minutes to spare / measles ...). When used in the _I have obtained_ (etc, as in _I've got this splinter out of my finger at last_, where many in the US would prefer 'gotten') sense,  it feels like more of a true present perfect. 'I have V-d' in the present perfect usually corresponds loosely to 'I did V'. // _I have got to_ is almost certainly best seen as an idiom (irregular syntax), and best left intact. 'I must.'

Comment: @Ameny: Please give a couple of sentences to demonstrate your examples.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Don't you think that the "I've got this splinter out of my finger" usage is more like "I have achieved my aim of" rather than "I have obtained"? I think that "I have got (obtained) my ticket for the train up Snowdon" and "I have got (achieved my aim of reaching) [to] the top of Snowdon" are two different usages for the same word. The splinter sentence is more like "I have got (achieved my aim of extracting) the splinter [out of]¦[from] my finger". I don't think that "I have obtained the splinter out of my finger" works at all.

Comment: @BoldBen Hence the _etc_; I didn't have space (or time) for three say examples. Space is limited in 'comments', but this question is too basic / overscoped if only asking for 'have got ...' examples, and I haven't got a reference to back my 'consider _have got to_ a lexeme' opinion (though I seem to remember John Lawler addressing this before). hence no 'answer'.

Comment: Yes, I posted regarding [the present tense perfect construction form _have got(ten)_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/76141/15299) and [the periphrastic modal construction _have (got) to_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/342532/15299).